# Running docker run as a separate user on OSX

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to make `docker` work for both my local user and a service user called `daemon` at the same time. Docker is working fine right now for my local user.

On linux, you'd add `daemon` to the `dockers` group which doesn't exist (literally as well as as a multi-user docker concept) on OS X.

If you try to run a command using `sudo -u daemon docker run foobar`, you'll first get this response:

`sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/docker: Permission denied`

You can fix this by running:

`ln -f -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/* /usr/local/bin`

But then, if you execute `sudo -u daemon docker run foobar` again, you'll get:

`Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.30/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

And here I'm stuck now.

FYI `/var/run/docker.sock` is a symbolic link pointing to `/Users/myusername/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/s60`, and some folks online seem to suggest to adjust permissions / groups (recursively) on `/Users/myusername/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker`, but that didn't seem to do anything for me, really.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using just Mac or Mac + Linux? Where is the daemon user running?

Comment: Just Mac. The same Mac has two users, myself and daemon.

Comment: I found a cumbersome workaround that involves a client-server setup to execute a command on behalf of somebody else while adjusting potential file permissions on the fly. No security whatsoever, but it works for testing stuff locally on Mac that you want to deploy on a *nix machine in production.  Will open-source and post here in the comments. Would still prefer a proper solution.

Comment: https://github.com/Jsonize/docker-polyfill/blob/master/demos/ffmpeg.js

Comment: This may be helpful for others without the OP's specific permissions issue: https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15